# How to use include in javascript in my code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

groupMapdata from API is coming as

```
[
    {
        "menu_id": 1666667,
        "menu_name_message_id": "menuName.viewgroups",
        "access_role_ids": "1,3"
    },
    {
        "menu_id": 1666668,
        "menu_name_message_id": "menuName.creategroup",
        "access_role_ids": "4,3,2,1"
    }
]
```

```js
checked = { groupMapData.length ? this.checkboxfunction("menuName.creategroup", 2, groupMapData) : false }
```

I have written checkbox function as:

```js
checkboxfunction = (menuname,role,data) => {
   return (data.includes(menuname) && data.includes(role))
}
```

Now it want checkbox function to return as true.

How to do this?

Comment: I should return checked or unchecked based on access role id and menu_name_message_id

Comment: like how to do that ?

Comment: You need `const checked = groupMapData.some(item => item.menu_name_message_id === "menuName.creategroup");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `Array.prototype.some` to detect the presence of at least one match.

Also, `Array.prototype.includes` will not locate the integer version of the number; you will need to map/parse the role ids into integers before checking.

```js
const checkboxFn = (menuName, role, menus) => {
  return menus.some(menu => {
    let nameMatches  = menu['menu_name_message_id'] === menuName,
        roleIncluded = menu['access_role_ids'].split(',')
                                              .map(n => parseInt(n, 10))
                                              .includes(role)
    return nameMatches && roleIncluded
  })
}
```

### Example

```js
const groupMapData = [{
  "menu_id": 1666667,
  "menu_name_message_id": "menuName.viewgroups",
  "access_role_ids": "1,3"
}, {
  "menu_id": 1666668,
  "menu_name_message_id": "menuName.creategroup",
  "access_role_ids": "4,3,2,1"
}]

const checkboxFn = (menuName, role, menus) => {
  return menus.some(menu => menu['menu_name_message_id'] === menuName
    && menu['access_role_ids'].split(',').map(n => parseInt(n, 10)).includes(role))
}

let checked = groupMapData.length
  ? checkboxFn("menuName.creategroup", 2, groupMapData)
  : false

console.log(checked) // true
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: How to do handle change for this  checkbox ?

Comment: handleChange = (name, role, data) => event => {

        let old_status_value = this.checkedfunction(name, role, data)
        if (old_status_value) {
            old_status_value = event.target.checked ? 1 : 0
        }
        this.setState({ data: data })
    } 



 onChange={this.handleChange('menuName.creategroup', 2, groupMapData)}

Comment: @NagaSai Although I would like to answer this here, that is an completely separate question from how "includes" works. I would just open a new question for that.

Comment: ,looking for solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want at least one object from data to contain at least one property you can use the following code

```
return (data.some(x=>x.menu_name_message_id = menumenuname) && data.some(x=>(x.roleId || '').indexOf(ole)!= -1)
```

If you want the at least one object to contain both newname and role you can use

```
  return (data.some(x=>x.menu_name_message_id = menumenuname) && (x.roleId || '').indexOf(ole)!= -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) simply performs a surface-level comparison on each element. This will always return `false` for objects unless they share the same ref.

```
// Array.prototype.includes() Example
const x = {}
const y = [x]
y.includes(x) // true
y.includes({}) // false
```

[`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) is more appropriate for comparing nested properties.

```
// Array.prototype.some() Example
const input = [
  {menu_id: 1666667, menu_name_message_id: 'menuName.viewgroups', access_role_ids: '1,3'}, 
  {menu_id: 1666668, menu_name_message_id: 'menuName.creategroup', access_role_ids: '4,3,2,1'}
]
const dataIncludesMenuNameAndRole = (data, menuName, role) => {
  const dataIncludesMenuName = data.some(element => element.menu_name_message_id === menuName)
  const dataIncludesRole = data.some(element => element.access_role_ids === role)
  return dataIncludesMenuName && dataIncludesRole
}
```

N.B. neither algorithm checks whether the same element contains matching props for both values, only that the values exist as props of elements within the array.